# Only evaluate position when reaching cumulative sum threshold in LazyList

Tags: scala

I would like to find a position of reaching a fixed threshold (e.g. 10) in a lazy list of 2's e.g.:

```
LazyList.
    continually(2).
    zipWithIndex.
    scanLeft((0,0)){case (acc, el) => (acc._1 + el._1, el._2)}.
    takeWhile(_._1 <= 10)
```

---

```
res72: LazyList[(Int, Int)] = LazyList(
  (0, 0),
  (2, 0),
  (4, 1),
  (6, 2),
  (8, 3),
  (10, 4)
)
```

Is it possible to do the same without collecting all the intermediate results, in functional way, only returning final position when the cumulative sum is reached, with `foldLeft` e.g. or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `collectFirst`, also I would move the `zipWithIndex` after the `scanLeft`

```scala
LazyList
  .continually(2)
  .scanLeft(0)((acc, x) => acc + x)
  .zipWithIndex
  .collectFirst {
    case (x, idx) if (x >= 10) => idx
  }
```

That returns an `Option[Int]` because the `collect` may never match, but you know it will in this case so you can just `.get` or `.getOrElse(new IllegalStateException("This should have never happened"))`